# Are very old CRT oscilloscopes possibly dangerous because of their X-rays?

Tags: oscilloscope, safety

I'm a novice who's looking for a very basic oscilloscope.  I found some on Ebay. Probably I'm much too careful, but I'm wondering if cathode ray screens from oscilloscopes of the 80s may leak dangerous levels of X-rays or if a broken case could increase the radiations.

Comment: CRTs don't emit too much x-ray radiation if operated at low enough anode voltages (I forget exactly what voltage, else I'd make this an answer instead of a comment); they're always operated below such voltages unless used for x-ray machines (where x-ray production is the intended purpose, of course).

Comment: IIRC, my old CRO used 3 kV for the acceleration voltage. Colour TVs that use 25 kV that use leaded glass screens, and of course medical x-ray machines usually run in the 100 kV ballpark.

Comment: 1980s isn't **that** old.  The scope I use for my hobby stuff was manufactured in 1965.  Whether a scope from the 1980s is adequate is a different question.  My old D43 is adequate because I don't do things that would require all the modern bells and whistles.  The same applies to a modern cheap scope - cheap won't do all the fancy stuff.

Comment: You may find that oscilloscope accelerating voltage is related to the advertised bandwidth...an oscilloscope with upper bandwidth of 20 MHz may only have a few kilovolt accelerating potential, whereas a 100 MHz 'scope has up to 10kV accelerating potential. There ARE some that use TV-like accelerating potential, but they're very exotic and NOT general-purpose instruments.

Comment: Check the CRT acceleration voltage. <20 kV, no issues. 35 kV sorting to get some x-rays and lead shielding may be used around the perimeter of the glass. 50+ kV and you are in x-ray territory.

Comment: I seem to recall that the problem with early vacuum-tube TVs was X-ray emission from the shunt stabiliser triode used to stabilise the EHT voltage; this worked by, essentially, wasting a lot of energy to keep the EHT voltage stable. In conditions of low image intensity, the plate (anode) (at 25 kV) could glow cherry red. A typical example is the PD500. People over-run them at 35-50 kV in home-made X-ray devices. In TV sets these tubes were covered by such things as leaded glass sleeves and metal mesh cages.

Comment: Before you buy one on ebay, maybe find a radio amateur club near you. Someone certainly has a CRT osci you can get much cheaper and without paying 20$ shipping. Well, I just gave 3 analog oscilloscopes away...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's not "very old" in terms of CRTs, but anyways:

your concerns aren't unfounded. CRTs *do* leak X-rays. However, the amount and hardness of the radiation scales with size of the CRT. And with an oscilloscope display, you're at the least end of all this, so, even if the protection isn't as good as in a consumer TV, you'll be fine.

Also, billions of people literally spent *years* in front of CRT TVs, and the population-wide effects are benign. How many hours a day do you intend to spend in front of that scope while it's running, for how many years?

Financially, buying a CRT oscilloscope almost certainly makes no sense for a beginner. Knowing how to operate one takes time, and some guidance, and the older they are, the more likely you'll need some calibration for it to be certainly useful. There's cheap digital oscilloscope modules, which are maybe analog-wise less nice than these old-time oscilloscopes, but much easier to deal with, use nearly no power, and being much smaller and harder to damage in transportation, much cheaper to ship.

Comment: Concur - there are even software-based scopes that are affordable.

Comment: I would prefer to have a knob rather than a pull down menu on my scope. And worst of all is a pc and a mouse on the workbench.

Comment: @DDuck hence my recommendation to go for digital oscilloscope thingies. I mean, even a 90€ (used) name-brand handheld "scope" multimeter has a superset of functions of a 1980's analog scope, and the screen isn't smaller.

Comment: but in the end, you're right: A solid CRT scope beats a cheap digital one in usability. Question is always: which bandwidth do I need? How much am I willing to spend on learning how to use it?

Comment: Worst bit is when the manufacturer redefines the timebase knob to something else

Comment: It used to be that you could get a used CRT oscilloscope for cheap (especially if you could get it from a lab clearance or garage/car boot sale). This was useful for beginners as it was a low cost option that you could do "risky" things with and just buy another used one if you fried it. Perhaps as more and more labs have switched to digital, that glut of analog CRT oscilloscopes has gone.

Comment: @Crazymoomin tickled my interest, checked my local auction site: they do still get sold. But yeah, garage sale, ideally from someone who you could offer a sixer of beer if he shows you how to use the device to visualize some audio (or something else easy and harmless) would be the place to get a scope, ideally. No better way making sure you know the tricks and limits.

Comment: @MarcusMüller based on a cursory eBay search, you can still find the odd bargain, but it's nowhere near as easy as it used to be. You could find dozens of clapped out machines for 15-20 USD, sometimes as low as 10 USD. People would often buy 2-3 and use them as secondary scopes, when they were concerned they might blow up their shiny new 200+ USD digital scope on something a bit experimental (cheap off-brand Chinese digital scopes didn't really exist back then).

Comment: I disagree on an analog 'scope not being worth it to a beginner.  I still say that one of my best purchases was a 4-channel Iwatsu for ~$100 on eBay when I was a freshman in college.  That was around 2006 or so, and it's still on my bench today.  I've never calibrated it, but I never intended it to be a precision thing anyway.  There's just something about direct manual control of something physical, that drives home what's really happening, in a way that software emulation can't.

Comment: THEN, when you switch to a digital 'scope, whether standalone or a USB "hockey puck" to a PC, you already have a physical sense of what's really happening.  The same is true for analog vs. digital audio mixing consoles, and pretty much anything else that has a useful analog version.

Comment: We don't entirely know CRT TVs are benign.  Unfortunately any X-ray related health effects may be masked behind more pedestrian health effects also associated with TVs, such as being sedentary. We do know that since the TV age began, there has been a swarm of new epidemics.  This is not news, but again largely attributed to being sedentary.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica let's take the statistics of how many people owned a CRT TV into account: there's very few health-related things that we have better knowledge of! There's enough people for every kind of control group.

Comment: `billions of people literally spent years in front of CRT TVs` When I was a kid my mother always made me keep at least 6 feet away from the TV for fear of... some kind of radiation.

Comment: @Michael I know I'm kinda mean about this, but, again: billions of people, with kids whose mother cared as much as yours, and other kids. No significant effects were found, as far as I know. Occam's razor says, lest you find clear indication of an effect in empirism, don't assume the effect exists.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I wasn't commenting on the effects of it or lack thereof

Answer (score 14):

The anode voltage in a cathode ray oscilloscope is a few thousand volts.  X-rays aren't produced until the that voltage exceeds 20 kV or more.  That only happened in color televisions.   Your oscilloscope will not produce X-rays.

Comment: Oh, it can **produce** soft x-rays. However, ordinary glass is very opaque to x-rays of a few keV energy.

Comment: I suspected I wouldn't get away with my over-simplified answer :)  Thanks for the added detail.

Comment: Some of the old scopes I've used had a sticker on it "Eigensichere Röhre, <40kV"... So it seems 40kV was considered safe :)

Comment: X-rays with high photon energies above 5–10 keV (below 0.2–0.1 nm wavelength) are called hard X-rays. (From Wikipedia) So you are wrong, Hard X-rays are produced above 5 to 10 keV, lower than 20 kV.

Answer (score 13):

You are not in danger. For occupational exposure (e.g. 8 hours a day, five days a week), the limit is often given as 50 mSv (or 50,000 μSv) in a single year with a maximum of 100 mSv or (100,000 μSv) in a consecutive five-year period. One study using CRT monitors concluded that because of the low dose rate, accurate dosimetry was difficult. It estimated the effective dose (ED) to an operator working in front of a monitor was 454 μSv yearly. That's less than one percent of the dose limit. It reduced to 16 μSv yearly after adding a conventional leaded glass sheet. I can't imagine that a CRT oscilloscope is going to vary wildly from this order of magnitude.

[X-ray dose estimation from cathode ray tube monitors](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25706133/)

Comment: And a link to a open source paper.

Comment: @DDuck - sorry, is that praise or criticism? Or neither?

Comment: A citation to a published reference is worth 10 k words. Every answer should have one. It's a complement.

Comment: An open source paper may not exist.

Answer (score 10):

Generally not an issue- the second anode voltage on oscilloscope tubes is only a few kV (resulting in negligible X-rays), compared to B&W and color TVs which have more like 15-30kV and commercial X-ray tubes which use more like 60-100kV accelerating potential to produce useful amounts of X-rays. Image from [here](https://www.testandmeasurementtips.com/8554/)

[image]

Comment: Dose is important here not photon energy. (Absorbed dose is measured in Gy, or Sv and is equivalent to J/kg) A few high energy photons might all go thru you but a lot of low energy ones may deposit their energy near your DNA.

Comment: @DDuck Except that you get little dose from soft x-rays because they can't leave the tube, or even penetrate much air.

Comment: A lot of diagnostic X-ray equipment is coming down in potential, too. I know at my last dental visit the kV marking was well under 60kV. They don't even offer me an apron and the technician doesn't wear one, either. I assume they can use such low energies as the targets (such as the CCD my dentist uses) is so much more sensitive than film.

Comment: 10-25MV!? Sounds fun to handle.

Comment: @DanSheppard I’ve used facilities where they did this (fortunately for radiation testing for space-bound electronics , not therapy, but I saw the setup for patients).

Comment: Radiotherapy machines want to keep the photon energy below 10 MV to avoid neutron activation of Al and Co in the machine.

Answer (score 3):

The case leakage may not be an issue, because if a CRT does emit X-rays, you are looking at the exposed screen anyway.

If the operating voltage of the CRT tube is low enough then it won't emit X-rays.

And the scope CRT is smaller than computer monitor and television CRTs which were relatively safe too.

Comment: That's only partwise true... the old scopes had small but very long tubes. Probably because they used electrostatic deflection instead of magnetic deflection of the beam (I can only guess why)...

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in other posts, it depends on:

- Anode voltage
- Shielding implemented in the device.

Anode voltages in CRT oscilloscopes vary extremely widely - from a below 1kV eg on small units with DG7-32 or similar tubes, to 24kV on units like the Tektronix models 502, 519, 7904. Very specialized devices (bespoke devices, obscure military gear) might possible go higher.

The reasons to use a higher voltage are:

- Sharper trace (that is certainly what you wanted in the 502 - it is low bandwidth)
- Higher brightness (especially with events that have a low repetition rate, where you rely on extreme brightness to make them visible to the eye or to photographic film)
- Higher bandwidth (more voltage, faster beam - faster beam, less time spent to go through the deflection plates. If the beam "stays" in the deflection field longer than it takes for a voltage change you want to record, there would be a conflicting hence and hither of deflection voltages applied to it, you would just thrash around the beam, but not properly deflect it! That's why you want it in the high-speed 7904 and 519, these are 500MHz/1000MHz devices. Other engineering tricks (deflection plates that are segmented and fed delayed versions of the input signal to each segment, so the deflection travels along the beam) were used in these very high speed designs in addition... interestingly, the 1000MHz 7104 model is only around 12kV, likely because the CRT in it is a special design that can easily be damaged by too much brightness.

There are also reasons to use a lower voltage:

- Cheaper build, easier to manage safety (high voltage, X-rays, ...) and reliability.
- Less chance to create so much brightness, when setup by an inexperienced user, that the phosphor or other parts of the CRT can get damaged.
- More sensitivity - the faster your beam, the more voltage you have to put on the deflection plates for the same deflection. Building amplifiers that can output 10s of volts at UHF frequencies was not trivial back then and isn't today. Also, that can become an EMI nightmare - you essentially are feeding the deflection plates with a transmitter, and you cannot shield them fully because anything except vacuum and glass will be in the way of getting a picture.

For comparison, 32kV was used in most color TVs, sometimes even higher in CRT projectors. There is lead in the glass envelope of these for a reason.

The bad rap early color TVs got for excessive X-ray production, by the way, is not entirely related to the CRT - early models use a parallel stabilizer circuit in the high voltage supply, based on a very big vacuum tube (eg the PD500 tube) that had much thinner glass (and usually was shielded in a lead enclosure for a reason...) and actually looked a bit like an X-ray tube... and behaved a lot like it.

For most CRT oscilloscopes you will find a manual online - since there were laws in place even then requiring manufacturers to document unwanted X-ray output of devices, you will probably find data in it.

Mind that X-rays from deceleration will go perpendicular to, not in the direction of the beam -- so you will be comparatively safe in front of the device.

Mind the elephant in the room - high voltage, when actually working inside these devices. Since they are designed as professional test equipment for trained users, these devices tend to be easy to open and run with the covers off. Be careful. But: the 12kV/24kV devices (even some 1950s era models!) will usually use some kind of inverter power supply for the anode voltage, like a non-ancient TV. These tend to have low current capacity and are usually regarded to be more likely to fling you across the room than plum kill you (does not mean they are harmless). Some older 2-4kV models use a conventional power supply that simply uses a high voltage from a winding on the mains transformer, and a conventional rectifier and filter circuit. Consider these circuits electric chair grade lethal!! There is a reason they stopped using that kind of circuit in TVs already in the 1940s....

By all means, do not discard or destroy old equipment out of fear - but be aware of what accelerating voltage etc apply to your gear!

Comment: Re *"high voltage, when actually working inside these devices"*: Only with power on? Or can energy be stored, the CRT acting like a giant capacitor?

Comment: The CRT is probably not you biggest worry with oscilloscopes.  Filter capacitors in the power supply circuits are. Especially with the mains-frequency/conventional type of power supply....